# Combine int & byte into long

Tags: java

I have two numbers: one is an int, other is byte. I want to create a single long value out of them in a way that person knowing the byte value can decipher original int from it. Whats the best way to do it?

Comment: Are you just wanting to store the two values in one long, or are you trying to hide the int value so that only the person who knows the byte value can obtain it?

Comment: only the person who knows the byte value can obtain it - thats correct

Comment: Then I would agree with st0le's answer. Although not a very secure encryption mechanism, at the very least it meets the requirements you have given.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming i understood your question correct,

The Simplest Solution, You Could XOR the 'int' using the 'byte'

Repeat the process to decrypt...

```
         byte key = 8;
        int secret = 123;
        System.out.println("Secret : " + secret);
        int encrypted = (secret ^ (key | (key << 8)));
        System.out.println("Encrypted : " + encrypted );
        int decrypt = (encrypted ^ (key | (key << 8)));
        System.out.println("Decrypted : " + decrypt );
```

The result is an 'int' but, you could always just cast it into a long...

Comment: I would just like to add that casting the result to a long is pretty much useless, since it will just add extra zeroes to the encrypted value.  If you really want to use longs then you could convert the single byte key and the 4 byte secret into 8 byte values before beginning the process. Although this won't really improve security of the encryption at least you will make use of the full 64bits rather than just having 32 zeroes added at the front.

Comment: Note that this has a few problems as encryption.  First off, you only "protected" the last two bytes of four.  Secondly, assuming that you (like most people most of the time) don't use really large numbers, the int you're encrypting will probably begin with zeroes.  Which means that an "attacker" could just take one of the early bytes of your number, and it will be the key (XORing something with all zeroes produces the original thing, unmodified).  If you want encryption, use real encryption - don't mess around with security.

Answer (score 1):

```
long mylong = (((long)mybyte) << 40) | myint;
```

To retrieve the original value:

```
int myorigint = (int)(mylong & ~(((long)mybyte) << 40));
```

But this requires 8-byte longs.  Which are not required by the C standard.  If a long is 4 bytes, you're out of luck.  This means `long` and `int` would have the same length.  If `sizeof(int)==sizeof(long)==4`, then asking to store an int and a byte in a long is asking to store 5 arbitrary bytes of information in 4 bytes.  Which is completely impossible.

Of course, there's also the trivial "solution":

```
long mylong = (long)myint;
```

and the reverse is:

```
int myint = (int)mylong;
```

Now, someone knowing (or not knowing!) the byte can retrieve the original data.

If you want a solution such that **only** someone knowing the correct byte can retrieve the original int, you can use this:

```
long mylong = (long)(myint-mybyte);
```

and reverse:

```
int myint = (int)(mylong+mybyte);
```

But know that encrypting four bytes with one byte will not be truly secure.  You should use a 4-byte one-time pad to encrypt four bytes.  If you have a four-byte key, use XOR for a truly unbreakable cipher.  No, really.

Comment: "If you have a four-byte key, use XOR for a truly unbreakable cipher."

It's true!

Comment: Indeed, i believe you gentleman are referring to the "one-time-pad" encryption. Which is indeed unbreakable iff the byte used to encrypt is truly randon AND only used ONCE. Wonder what the OP is trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to apply a reversible function the number of times indicated by the byte.

To get the original number back just apply the inverse function the same number of times.

e.g.

```
public static int encrypt(int value, byte key) {
  int result=value;
  for (int i=0; i<=(key&255); i++) {
    result=Integer.rotateRight(result,7)^(i+0xCAFEBABE);
  } 
  return result;
}
```

Finding the reverse function left as an exercise for the reader.....